# Login without username and password from the web browser on Windows

Tags: windows, single-sign-on, ntlm, browser

I heard that on Windows you can login from a web browser to the web server without going through the usual login entering username and password but using instead the credentials from Windows directly, using  the NTLM protocol.

How is this achieved? Does the web server need to support some additional authentication?

**Update:** I'm asking for a generic web server, not just IIS. How to do that on Apache for instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The webserver just needs to be configured to support Windows authentication (which will be NTLM, or - better - Kerberos if both client and server are W2K or later). I believe that IIS or Apache can be configured to do that.

The browser also has to support this - at least IE does so (not sure about the others, it may be possible). *edit: looks like firefox has some support for this too, and safari on MacOS*

*edit: for details on apache, google modules for NTLM authentication. Kerberos modules also exist. as per other answers, this really only works on an Intranet - not just because the browser needs to be in an Intranet zone (only applies to IE), but because any intervening firewall will typically stop this working, and because the necessary interdomain trusts will probably not exist. It's also a bit trickier to make work if the apache server is on UNIX, and especially if you also have Kerberos servers on UNIX in the mix, but still possible.*

Answer (score 3):

It will only be seamless in a specific situation; namely the webserver needs to support NTLM (for example, IIS), and it needs to be in a zone that the client is configured to trust (The "Intranet Zone" in IE parlance, unless the end user has tweaked their settings)

Answer (score 2):

If your webserver and client pc's are on a network secured by Active Directory or similar, you can set 'Windows Integrated Security' in IIS on the web server for the website which automatically logs in all I.E clients (That are allowed).

Answer (score 1):

As stated previously, NTLM is typically used if your back end is Windows Managed (MS Active Directory).  However, there are also modules available for Apache that will tie into this: [mod_ntlm](http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/).

Since this is it's own protocol, it is required that the browser is able to understand this protocol and reply to the authentication challenges.  I don't know which browsers support this off hand, but my assumption would be that most do.

From my experience, kerberos is more of a prefered method, but I have not worked with it much, so unfortunately, I don't have much advise as far as that goes.

On a side note, I recall reading somewhere that the JRE also has ways of tying into NTLM on your web server in order to obtain identity information for the authenticated user.  As stated previously, .NET has support for this as well.

Also, Firefox does not support NTLM by default but it can be configured using the following tut: http://www.crossedconnections.org/w/?p=89

Answer (score 0):

If you set the IIS settings to require authentication then your users will need to log in to access the page.  They then have any rights (if not an interface) to anything on that server that they would if they logged in the normal way (from the console).

Other than this, I am not sure what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. It is often used in intranet applications where users are. windows uses *NTLM* or *Kerberos* to authorize the user against a central service, typically *Active Directory* on the windows platform. On the .NET platform the current user information can be accessed through the *System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity* instance.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look into Jespa.  It seems a little bit more straight forward than Kerberos but provides good ntlm sso capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for more information about Kerberos (because NTLM, even v2, become deprecated with AD 2008), and I found this article, explaining how make it work with Apache (as you mentionned it).
http://blog.scottlowe.org/2006/08/10/kerberos-based-sso-with-apache/

This question is probably outdated (or at least solved), but if it can help someone ...